# My Android app is showing bounds of TextViews but the actual TextViews aren't visible, what should I do?

Tags: java, android, xml, textview, android-elevation

This is the code that I have used in my Android app to display certain info related to some person's BMI.

Few minutes ago, the code was working and everything was perfect but since I have made some changes that I don't remember specifically, the TextViews are not showing up, I don't know why, I am just a beginner. Do you have any idea about this problem ?

It seems that the textviews are there since when I switched on display bounds in developer options, the bounds are being shown as intended but I don't know what has gone wrong.

```
<LinearLayout
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="16dp"
android:clipToPadding="false"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:background="@color/transparent"
android:id="@+id/result_parent">
<TextView
android:id="@+id/result_text_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:elevation="10dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="34sp" />
<TextView
android:id="@+id/category_text_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:paddingTop="8dp"
android:paddingBottom="8dp"
android:focusable="true"
android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
android:elevation="10dp"
android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
android:gravity="center_horizontal"
android:textColor="#ffffff"
android:textSize="34sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: can you post your activity code?

Comment: your text color is white according to that your background color of layout or theme needs suitable if your background theme also white then it will be not shown cause of same color

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you have set the color of your textview to white with below line: and your background is probably white too.

```
android:textColor="#ffffff"
```

change it to something else:

android:textColor="#000000"

Comment: result_container.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.zero));
            result.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.zero));
            category.setTextColor(ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.zero));
            category.setText("Please enter your height and weight above!");

Comment: But the problem is that even after I use the java code given in the previous comment, the whole area surrounded by the linear layout is covered by a single solid color as if the linear layout has been placed on top, btw R.color.zero is sort of brown

Comment: what do i need to tell more ? any idea

Comment: I replaced every value of R.color.transparent and Color.TRANSPARENT with white color values and now that works for me ! Thanks for help